# Create separate table for each user to store data or use a single table

Tags: java, mysql, database

I know there are many queries related to this question but my problem
is different.I want to make a Password Manager application which
stores host name,username,password,notes etc for each user. I can not
store these information in user's column as there are multiple rows
for each user's data.

So is it right in my case to create a separate table for each user
or I create a single table named "Host" and add all passwords there
with foreign  key "username" as primary key in this table.Whenever any
query is executed it  display only particular user's rows.

> User Table:- id:**username**:email:password:security question:answer
>
> Host Table:- **username**:s.no.:host name:host username:password:notes

Which approach would be more effective and if there an better
alternative please let me know.I am posting my question first time
after gaining a lot from this website so please excuse me for my bad
grammar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A correct approach would resemple something like this:

```
Users
------
id | username | email | encryptedpassword | security_question | encryptedsecurityanswer

Hosts
------
id | user_id | name | notes
```

Ceate a table for users and hosts.  These tables are joined by the Users.id to Hosts.user_id relationship.

Comment: Yes, keeping the User's app. related data in `Users` table, and other informative data in diff. table.

Answer (score 1):

Creating Tables for each user is a BAD approach. If your going to use Plan A it will create database OVER HEAD when increase in number of users.

Use Plan B

```
 Host Table:-username:s.no.:host name:host username:password:notes
```